# Postgres with CTE and return multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to use a CTE to format a complex query and return multiple tables.

below code：

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."postgres_return_mutiple_table"(refcursor,refcursor)
RETURNS SETOF "pg_catalog"."refcursor" AS $BODY$
declare return_agents alias for $1;
return_agentpayrate alias for $2;
BEGIN
        with t_agents as (
                    select * from agents join .... where .. /*maybe complex query*/
        ),
        t_agentpayrate as (
                select * from t_agents join .... where .. /*maybe complex query*/
        )
        OPEN return_agents FOR select * from t_agents
        RETURN NEXT return_agents;
        OPEN return_agentpayrate FOR
                     select * from t_agentpayrate RETURN 
                NEXT t_agentpayrate;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

When I run this function, it errors:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "OPEN"
> LINE 12:   OPEN return_agents FOR select * from t_agents; 
>            ^
> , Time: 0.001000s
> ```

Comment: Can you post a link to a piece of documentation that suggests `WITH` can be used before opening of a cursor like you did? I have doubts that this is possible. You can try to move/copy the `WITH ...` after the `FOR` but then you had the CTE in there twice. But a use of a CTE seems a little useless there anyway.

Comment: Hi  I'm not sure if this is correct. I used to use SQL server. can you  show 
 a example？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_get_available_enterprise(
"shortname" varchar,
"filter" varchar, 
"recordpage" int4, 
"pageindex" int4,
refcursor,
refcursor
) returns setof refcursor
as
$$
declare avail_entp  alias for $5;
        avail_entp_count alias for $6;
begin
   open avail_entp for 
         WITH available_enterprise AS (
                 SELECT distinct entinfo,ent.entname,ent.entabbr FROM get_agent_nocontian_entpaymenttype(shortname,filter,recordpage,pageindex) 
                 JOIN wxbsenterprise ent  on ent.entname = output_entname
                 where (("filter"!='' and (ent.entname like "filter" or entinfo like "filter" or entabbr like "filter"))
                 or ("filter"='' and 1=1))
                 limit recordpage offset (pageindex-1)*recordpage    
          ),
          enterpriserate_link_agent as(
                 select * from agententerprises 
                 where entname=@entname and level=1 
                 and (validate = true or (validate = false and enddate is not null and enddate >= current_date))
          )
          select * from available_enterprise;
   return next avail_entp;
   open avail_entp_count for 
                         WITH available_enterprise_count as (
                                         SELECT distinct entinfo,ent.entname,entabbr FROM get_agent_nocontian_entpaymenttype(shortname,filter,recordpage,pageindex) as epna 
                                                                JOIN wxbsenterprise ent  on ent.entname = output_entname
                         )
                        select count(*) from available_enterprise_count; 
   return next avail_entp_count;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```